# Is the MOSFET NTE2390 broken if connecting only source and drain powers a motor?

Tags: mosfet

I've got a small motor wired to the drain of an [NTE2390](https://www.frys.com/product/1000523?site=sr:SEARCH:MAIN_RSLT_PG), with the other end of the motor hooked up to ground.

When I connect to the source of the MOSFET to power, the motor starts turning even though there are no wires connected to the gate.

**Does this mean my MOSFET is broken, or is my circuit wrong?**

Comment: Ground the gate and see what happens, first.

Comment: @jonk, Just tried that, same result.

Comment: Wire the gate to the Source, and test. In enhancement-mode power MOSFETs, that is the condition wherein you expect NO CONDUCTION.

Answer (score 0):

> - I've got a small motor wired to the drain of an NTE2390
> - the other end of the motor hooked up to ground.
> - the source of the MOSFET to power

That MOSFET is an N-channel device and its body diode will freely conduct current from a positive supply to a load when incorrectly wired into a circuit: -

[image]

You are using it incorrectly. If you want to connect source to positive and load to drain (returning current to ground) then use a P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: Could you explain how to wire it correctly so that the the motor will turn when voltage is supplied to the gate?

Comment: Connect source to 0 volts and motor between drain and power positive. Drive gate with control voltage.